# Deep len, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

Goal: find total number of elements in a nested iterable of arbitrary depth. My shot:

```py
import numpy as np

def deeplen(item, iterables=(list, tuple, dict, np.ndarray)):
    # return 1 and terminate recursion when `item` is no longer iterable
    if isinstance(item, iterables):
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            item = item.values()
        return sum(deeplen(subitem) for subitem in item)
    else:
        return 1
```

Naturally there are more iterables than shown, but these cover the vast majority of use cases; more can be added, with per-istance treatment if needed (e.g. `dict`), so the approach is *extendable*.

Any better approaches? Can be in: (1) performance; (2) readability; (3) generality (more iterables)

---

**Performance test**:

```py
def test_deeplen(iters=200):
    def _make_bignest():
        arrays = [np.random.randn(100, 100), np.random.uniform(30, 40, 10)]
        lists = [[1, 2, '3', '4', 5, [6, 7]] * 555, {'a': 1, 'b': arrays[0]}]
        dicts = {'x': [1, {2: [3, 4]}, [5, '6', {'7': 8}] * 99] * 55,
                 'b': [{'a': 5, 'b': 3}] * 333, ('k', 'g'): (5, 9, [1, 2])}
        tuples = (1, (2, {3: np.array([4., 5.])}, (6, 7, 8, 9) * 21) * 99,
                  (10, (11,) * 5) * 666)
        return {'arrays': arrays, 'lists': lists,
                'dicts': dicts, 'tuples': tuples}

    def _print_report(bignest, t0):
        t = time() - t0
        print("{:.5f} / iter ({} iter avg, total time: {:.3f}); sizes:".format(
            t / iters, iters, t))
        print("bignest:", deeplen(bignest))
        print(("{} {}\n" * len(bignest)).format(
            *[x for k, v in bignest.items()
              for x in ((k + ':').ljust(8), deeplen(v))]))

    bignest = _make_bignest()
    t0 = time()
    for _ in range(iters):
        deeplen(bignest)
    _print_report(bignest, t0)
```

```py
>> test_deeplen(1000)
0.02379 / iter (1000 iter avg, total time: 23.786); sizes:
bignest: 53676
arrays:  10010
lists:   13886
dicts:   17170
tuples:  12610
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution can be implemented in terms of two different paradigms.

### Look Before You Leap (LBYL)

You can test if an object supports a certain *interface* using `collections.abc`, where `abc` stands for Abstract Base Classes.
The module provides the [`Iterable` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable).
If an object is an instance of that class, it can be considered iterable.
How the object handles this under the hood, we do not care for.
This can be used to test for iterables.

Secondly, there is `Mapping` to detect types like `dict`s.
This can go where you currently test for `isinstance(item, dict)`.

Checking if an object supports what you plan on doing to or with it is the *Look Before You Leap* style.
Unfortunately, this approach is slower than before.
However, the loss in performance is justifiable in the face of the gained value.
You can now support *any* iterable anyone can throw at you, and shift the responsibility of handling the actual iteration to them.
Otherwise, you would have to add every conceivable iterable to `iterables=(..)`.
You already noticed that this is not feasible.

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable, Mapping

def deeplen_lbyl(item):
    """Returns the number of non-iterable items in arbitrarily nested iterators.
    """
    if isinstance(item, Iterable) and not isinstance(item, str):
        if isinstance(item, Mapping):
            item = item.values()
        return sum(deeplen_lbyl(subitem) for subitem in item)
    else:
        return 1
```

### Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission (EAFP)

This is an alternative approach, relying on just going ahead and letting things fail, then catching expected errors and handling them.
It is often considered the Pythonic one.
Its large advantage is its flexibility.
If there is a large number of both allowed and disallowed situations, adding all allowed situations to some sort of whitelist (like `isinstance`) can be tedious.
This is where the ABCs helped in the *LBYL* style above.
The *EAFP* style does not rely on ABCs or probing for interfaces.

```py
def deeplen_eafp(item):
    """Returns the number of non-iterable items in arbitrarily nested iterators.
    """
    try:
        iter(item)
    except TypeError:
        return 1

    if isinstance(item, str):
        return 1

    try:
        item = item.values()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    return sum(deeplen_eafp(subitem) for subitem in item)
```

In the `Iterable` class description, it says that calling `iter` is the only save way of detecting an iterable.
So this is what is done here.
Note that there is also [a different viewpoint to that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61139278/11477374).

`TypeError` is raised if the object did not like being iterated over.

Now, `str` passes both `isinstance` and `iter` checks, so the guard clause is needed here, too.
It is required to avoid infinite recursion, since `str` would remain infinitely iterable.

If the `values()` attribute is not available, a `Mapping`-like object is not present.
Accordingly, `AttributeError` is raised, and we keep the original `item`.

### Performance

Python has, unlike other languages, cheap error handling. A `try` block is cheap if it does not raise an exception.
However, the more we run into walls blindly, the more errors are thrown out the behind in the `try` blocks.
This is slowing that approach down.

---

I did not touch your `test_deeplen` function.
Using it, all three (yours and the two presented here) functions return the same output.

`deeplen_lbyl` and `deeplen_eafp` are equally slower than your function, in the ballpark:

```
deeplen_lbyl:
  0.02510 / iter (10 iter avg, total time: 0.251); sizes:
  bignest: 53676
  arrays:  10010
  lists:   13886
  dicts:   17170
  tuples:  12610

deeplen_eafp:
  0.02497 / iter (10 iter avg, total time: 0.250); sizes:
  bignest: 53676
  arrays:  10010
  lists:   13886
  dicts:   17170
  tuples:  12610

deeplen from question:
  0.01695 / iter (10 iter avg, total time: 0.170); sizes:
  bignest: 53676
  arrays:  10010
  lists:   13886
  dicts:   17170
  tuples:  12610
```

Comment: Quality answer. Follow-up: how do we know if "any" iterable will be accounted for correctly? Can't one make a custom type that is like `dict` in that, when iterated over, doesn't return 'values' - but unlike `dict`, values can't be accessed via `.values()`?

Comment: Good question, I had similar concerns. I believe that the test for `isinstance(..., Mapping)` is not passed if `values` is not available in the first place. Having a mapping but not implementing the callable `values` attribute seems strange. I urge you to ask a new question about this!

Comment: From a real use-case: arrays can be quite expensive for all our `deeplen` versions; the following gives a big speedup: `if isinstance(item, np.ndarray): return item.size`. (P.S. I ultimately went with your LBYL, for its clarity and generality)

Comment: Real use-case 2.0: `eafp` is more reliable via `try-iter` - the small performance difference is of no consequence majority time anyway. Pretty sure the final winner is **deeplen_eafp + numpy check**.

Comment: Could you rerun tests with `iters=1000`? I just noticed you used `=10`, which is quite small and may have yielded misleading results.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon On my machine, running it with `1000` does not change anything, and the relations between the three remain the same, see also here: https://repl.it/repls/SevereHonorableRelationalmodel

Comment: Strange, I've even benchmarked on a [Colab VM](https://colab.research.google.com/) CPU - guess 'vanilla' does win on some machines after all. I originally included `_deeplen_fast` and `_deeplen_full`, former accessible via `deeplen(fast=True)` but dropped it after new benchmarks - guess it's an option worth noting.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a faster and more general algorithm than in posted alternatives:

```py
import numpy as np
from collections.abc import Mapping

def deeplen(item):
    if isinstance(item, np.ndarray):
        return item.size
    try:
        list(iter(item))
    except:
        return 1
    if isinstance(item, str):
        return 1
    if isinstance(item, Mapping):
        item = item.values()
    return sum(deeplen(subitem) for subitem in item)
```

**Advantages**:

1. *Speed*: `.size` for Numpy arrays is much faster than recursive-iterative `len`. Also, there isn't much performance difference between the original `deeplen` and current `deeplen` (if excluding `.size` advantage), but `deeplen_lbyl` is slowest by 40% (tested w/ `iters=1000` on `bignest`).
2. *Generality*: neither `isinstance(, Iterable)` nor `try-iter` are sufficient to determine whether `item` is 'truly' iterable; some objects (e.g. TensorFlow [`Tensor`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L266)) support creating *generators* but not *consuming* them without [dedicated methods](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/map_fn.py#L47) for iterating. It does become a question of whose `len` we're measuring, since an arbitrarily-sized `Tensor` will count as `1` per above algorithm - if this isn't desired, then object-specific treatment is required.

Credit to @AlexPovel for originally suggesting `try-iter` and `isinstance(, Mapping)`.

Comment: Interesting! I know nothing of `Tensor`, but it not responding to the `iter` built-in is strange (as it's ["the only reliable way to determine whether an object is iterable"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable). But there's perhaps a reason I am unaware of.

Comment: @AlexPovel Update #3 [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/242369/deep-map-python) gives some explanation; TL;DR - just like `list` and `dict` have  different "access specifiers" (`__getitem__`), a `Tensor` has one of its own that has no Pythonic equivalent (not bracket-able), requiring a method. `list(iter())` ensures `item` is _Python-iterable_ - and if it isn't, `deeplen` will have trouble.