# Deep map, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

Goal: apply `fn` to every element of an arbitrarily nested iterable (tuple, list, dict, np.ndarray), including to iterables. Ex:

```py
def fn1(x, key):  # ignore `key` for now
    return str(x) if not isinstance(x, Iterable) else x
def fn2(x, key):
    return x ** 2 if isinstance(x, (int, float, np.generic)) else x

arr = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(2, 2))
obj = (1, {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': ('5', 6., (7, 8)), 'd': 9}, arr)

deepmap(obj, fn1) == ('1', {'a': '3', 'b': '4', 'c': ('5', '6.0', ('7', '8')), 'd': '9'}, 
                      array([[6, 1], [5, 4]]))
deepmap(obj, fn2) == (1, {'a': 9, 'b': 16, 'c': ('5', 36.0, (49, 64)), 'd': 81}, 
                      array([[36,  1], [25, 16]]))
```

[`deeplen`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/241654/deep-len-python) should also be a special case of `deepmap`, with proper `fn` (just a demo, don't care for optimizing this):

```py
def deeplen(obj):
    count = [0]
    def fn(x, key):
        if not isinstance(x, Iterable) or isinstance(x, str):
            count[0] += 1
        return x
    deepmap(obj, fn)
    return count[0]

deeplen(obj) == 12
```

My working implementation, along tests, below. Unsure this works without OrderedDict (Python >=3.6 default); it does if key order doesn't change even as values are changed (but no keys inserted/popped). A resolution is appending actual Mapping keys to `key` instead of their index, but this complicates implementing. (As for why pass `key` to `fn`: we can implement e.g. `deepequal`, comparing `obj` against another obj; this requires key info. Also [`deepcopy`](https://repl.it/repls/SilverUnnaturalGigahertz).)

Any improvements? I haven't tested exhaustively - maybe there are objects for which this fails, hence subject to extendability. Performance/readability could be better also.

---

**Visualization**: `deepmap` traverses a nest *left-to-right*, *inward-first*: ([code](https://repl.it/repls/UnhealthyUnrulyEyestrain))

[image]

- *Purple*: `fn` applied to iterable / element
- *Blue*: `tuple()` applied to list
- *Green*: `list()` applied to tuple
- *Grey*: iterable exit; dropping `key[-1]` and decrementing `depth` - no operation
- *Green + Purple*: `fn(item)` is only assigned to `list`-cast tuple; no 'intermediate' state
- *Empty*: see placement of `print` in linked code; this is to show effect of list+fn

---

**Implementation**: [live demo](https://repl.it/@OverLordGoldDra/WealthyMoralEngines)

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping

def deepmap(obj, fn):
    def deepget(obj, key=None, drop_keys=0):
        if not key or not obj:
            return obj
        if drop_keys != 0:
            key = key[:-drop_keys]
        for k in key:
            if isinstance(obj, Mapping):
                k = list(obj)[k]  # get key by index (OrderedDict, Python >=3.6)
            obj = obj[k]
        return obj

    def dkey(x, k):
        return list(x)[k] if isinstance(x, Mapping) else k

    def nonempty_iter(item):
        # do not enter empty iterable, since nothing to 'iterate' or apply fn to
        try:
            list(iter(item))
        except:
            return False
        return not isinstance(item, str) and len(item) > 0

    def _process_key(obj, key, depth, revert_tuple_keys, recursive=False):
        container = deepget(obj, key, 1)
        item      = deepget(obj, key, 0)

        if nonempty_iter(item) and not recursive:
            depth += 1
        if len(key) == depth:
            if key[-1] == len(container) - 1:  # iterable end reached
                depth -= 1      # exit iterable
                key = key[:-1]  # drop iterable key
                if key in revert_tuple_keys:
                    supercontainer = deepget(obj, key, 1)
                    k = dkey(supercontainer, key[-1])
                    supercontainer[k] = tuple(deepget(obj, key))
                    revert_tuple_keys.pop(revert_tuple_keys.index(key))
                if depth == 0 or len(key) == 0:
                    key = None  # exit flag
                else:
                    # recursively exit iterables, decrementing depth
                    # and dropping last key with each recursion
                    key, depth = _process_key(obj, key, depth, revert_tuple_keys,
                                              recursive=True)
            else:  # iterate next element
                key[-1] += 1
        elif depth > len(key):
            key.append(0)  # iterable entry
        return key, depth

    key = [0]
    depth = 1
    revert_tuple_keys = []

    if not nonempty_iter(obj):  # nothing to do here
        raise ValueError(f"input must be a non-empty iterable - got: {obj}")
    elif isinstance(obj, tuple):
        obj = list(obj)
        revert_tuple_keys.append(None)  # revert to tuple at function exit

    while key is not None:
        container = deepget(obj, key, 1)
        item      = deepget(obj, key, 0)

        if isinstance(container, tuple):
            ls = list(container)  # cast to list to enable mutating
            ls[key[-1]] = fn(item, key)

            supercontainer = deepget(obj, key, 2)
            k = dkey(supercontainer, key[-2])
            supercontainer[k] = ls
            revert_tuple_keys.append(key[:-1])  # revert to tuple at iterable exit
        else:
            k = dkey(container, key[-1])
            container[k] = fn(item, key)

        key, depth = _process_key(obj, key, depth, revert_tuple_keys)

    if None in revert_tuple_keys:
        obj = tuple(obj)
    return obj
```

**Testing**:

```py
import numpy as np
from collections.abc import Iterable
from copy import deepcopy
from time import time
from deepmap import deepmap


def fn1(x, key):
    return str(x) if not isinstance(x, Iterable) else x

def fn2(x, key):
    return x ** 2 if isinstance(x, (int, float, np.generic)) else x

def fn3(x, key):
    return str(x)

def make_bigobj():
    arrays = [np.random.randn(100, 100), np.random.uniform(30, 40, 10)]
    lists = [[1, 2, '3', '4', 5, [6, 7]] * 555, {'a': 1, 'b': arrays[0]}]
    dicts = {'x': [1, {2: [3, 4]}, [5, '6', {'7': 8}] * 99] * 55,
             'b': [{'a': 5, 'b': 3}] * 333, ('k', 'g'): (5, 9, [1, 2])}
    tuples = (1, (2, {3: np.array([4., 5.])}, (6, 7, 8, 9) * 21) * 99,
              (10, (11,) * 5) * 666)
    return {'arrays': arrays, 'lists': lists,
            'dicts': dicts, 'tuples': tuples}

def deeplen(obj):
    count = [0]
    def fn(x, key):
        if not isinstance(x, Iterable) or isinstance(x, str):
            count[0] += 1
        return x
    deepmap(obj, fn)
    return count[0]

#### CORRECTNESS  ##############################################################
np.random.seed(4)
arr = np.random.randint(0, 9, (2, 2))
obj = (1, {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': ('5', 6., (7, 8)), 'd': 9}, {}, arr)

out1 = deepmap(deepcopy(obj), fn1)
assert str(out1) == ("('1', {'a': '3', 'b': '4', 'c': ('5', '6.0', ('7', '8'))"
                      ", 'd': '9'}, {}, array([[7, 5],\n       [1, 8]]))")
out2 = deepmap(deepcopy(obj), fn2)
assert str(out2) == ("(1, {'a': 9, 'b': 16, 'c': ('5', 36.0, (49, 64)), "
                      "'d': 81}, {}, array([[49, 25],\n       [ 1, 64]]))")
out3 = deepmap(deepcopy(obj), fn3)
assert str(out3) == (r"""('1', "{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': ('5', 6.0, (7, 8)), """
                      r"""'d': 9}", '{}', '[[7 5]\n [1 8]]')""")
try:
    deepmap([], fn1)
except ValueError:
    pass
except:
    print("Failed to catch invalid input")

#### PERFORMANCE  ##############################################################
bigobj  = make_bigobj()

_bigobj = deepcopy(bigobj)
t0 = time()
assert deeplen(bigobj) == 53676
print("deeplen:     {:.3f} sec".format(time() - t0))
assert str(bigobj) == str(_bigobj)  # deeplen should not mutate `bigobj`

bigobj = deepcopy(_bigobj)
t0 = time()
deepmap(bigobj, fn1)
print("deepmap-fn1: {:.3f} sec".format(time() - t0))

# deepmap-fn2 takes too long
```

```
deeplen:     0.856 sec
deepmap-fn1: 0.851 sec
```

---

**Updates**:

1. `deepmap` failed with *empty iterables*, e.g. `[]`, `{}` - fixed, tests updated. Also added invalid input handling.
2. Improved `nonempty_iter` to use [`try-iter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable#answer-36407550), and applied it as check on `obj` at input. Unsure what test to add as my use-case is TensorFlow - a more general suggestion is welcome.
3. Improved `nonempty_iter` again. `try-iter` is insufficient to determine whether `obj` is *Python-iterable*; some objects (e.g. TensorFlow [`Tensor`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L266)) support creating *generators* but not *consuming* them without [dedicated methods](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/map_fn.py#L47). It does become a question of what exactly we're mapping and with what methods; in that case, object-specific treatment is required.

   - This can be considered a limitation rather than improvement, as it doesn't allow non-Pythonic iteration (non-indices/hash keys) - but an exception will be thrown unless improvement #2 below is implemented, and it's an unlikely edge case anyway.

---

**Possible improvements**:

1. `fn` could also apply to Mappable `.keys()` instead of `.values()` only
2. Only Pythonic iterables are iterated with current implementation (see Update 3). More general access and assignment specifiers can be implemented - but code beyond `deepget` would require modifying (e.g. `supercontainer[k]`).

Comment: `deepmap((1, 2, [3, 4]), fn3)` returns `('1', 2', '[3, 4]')`.  I expected `('1', '2', ['3', '4'])`.  `deepmap` should apply the function (`fn3`) recursively to all the nested elements (e.g., the 3 and 4) not just to the top level elements (e.g. [3, 4]). Right?

Comment: @RootTwo Negative; note the goal statement: "apply `fn` to every element of an arbitrarily nested iterable (tuple, list, dict, np.ndarray), **including to iterables**" - so `[3, 4]` is cast to string before it can be iterated; `fn1` yields the behavior you describe. This is intended, as it gives more flexibility to what we can do with `fn`.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the interface between `deepmap` and the function.  How does `deepmap` determine whether to recursively apply a function to an iterable, a la `fn1`, versus to apply the function to the whole iterable, a la `fn3`.  Does the recursion occur when the function returns the argument unchanged?  In this call, `deepmap((1, 2, [3, 4]), fn3)`, the first argument is an iterable, so `fn3` should be applied to the iterable as a whole and return `"(1, 2, [3, 4])"`.

Comment: @RootTwo Added visual; good last point - the "whole" iterable is exempt from `fn`, on logic that it is the "object" whose internals we're mapping, and that we can just `fn(obj)` if needed, no `deepmap` necessary.